# How to skip irregular header information of a Flat File in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, business-intelligence, flat-file

I have a file like as seen below: Just Ex:

```
kwqif h;wehf uhfeqi f ef
fekjfnkenfekfh  ijferihfq eiuh qfe iwhuq fbweq
fjqlbflkjqfh iufhquwhfe hued liuwfe
jewbkfb flkeb l jdqj jvfqjwv yjwfvjyvdfe
enjkfne khef kurehf2 kuh fkuwh lwefglu 
gjghjgyuhhh jhkvv   vytvgyvyv   vygvyvv
gldw    nbb ouyyu   buyuy   bjbuy   
ID  Name    Address
1   Andrew  UK
2   John    US
3   Kate    AUS
```

I want to dynamically skip header information and load flatfile to DB
Like below:

```
    ID  Name    Address
    1   Andrew  UK
    2   John    US
    3   Kate    AUS
```

The header information may vary (not fixed no. of rows) from file to file.

Any help..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The generic SSIS components cannot meet this requirement. You need to code for this e.g. in an SSIS Script task.

I would code that script to read through the file looking for that header row `ID Name Address`, and then write that line and the rest of the file out to a new file.

Then I would load that new file using the SSIS Flat File Source component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mike Honey, I am not good at writing script in script task, is that code available any where here. Can you please provide link of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to avoid a script task if you'd prefer not to use one. I'll offer a few ideas here as it's not entirely clear which will be best from your example data. To some extent it's down to personal preference anyway, and also the different ideas might help other people in future:

**Convert ID and ignore failures:** Set the file source so that it expects however many columns you're forced into having by the header rows, and simply pull everything in as string data. In the data flow - immediately after the source component - add a data conversion component or conditional split component. Try to convert the first column (with the ID) into a number. Add a row count component and set the error output of the data conversion or conditional split to be redirected to that row count rather than causing a failure. Send the rest of the data on its way through the rest of your data flow.

This should mean you only get the rows which have a numeric value in the ID column - but if there's any chance you might get real failures (i.e. the file comes in with invalid ID values on rows you otherwise would want to load), then this might be a bad idea. You could drop your failed rows into a table where you can check for anything unexpected going on.

**Check for known header values/header value attributes:** If your header rows have other identifying features then you could avoid relying on the error output by simply setting up the conditional split to check for various different things: exact string matches if the header rows always start with certain values, strings over a certain length if you know they're always much longer than the ID column can ever be, etc.

**Check for configurable header values**: You could also put a list of unacceptable ID values into a table, and then do a lookup onto this table, throwing out the rows which match the lookup - then if you need to update the list of header values, you just have to update the table and not your whole SSIS package.

**Check for acceptable ID values:** You could set up a table like the above, but populate this with numbers - not great if you have no idea how many rows might be coming in or if the IDs are actually unique each time, but if you're only loading in a few rows each time and they always start at 1, you could chuck the numbers 1 - 100 into a table and throw away and rows you load which don't match when doing a lookup onto this table.

**Staging table:** This is probably the way I'd deal with it if I didn't want to use a script component, but in part that's because I tend to implement initial staging tables like this anyway, and I'm comfortable working in SQL - so your mileage may vary.

Pick up the file in a data flow and drop it into a staging table as-is. Set your staging table data types to all be large strings which you know will hold the file data - you can always add a derived column which truncates things or set the destination to ignore truncation if you think there's a risk of sometimes getting abnormally large values. In a separate data flow which runs after that, use SQL to pick up the rows where ID is numeric, and carry on with the rest of your processing.

This has the added bonus that you can just pick up the columns which you know will have data you care about in (i.e. columns 1 through 3), you can do any conversions you need to do in SQL rather than in SSIS, and you can make sure your columns have sensible names to be used in SSIS.